# How to send a function to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to know how I can send a function from my parent component to my child component. Because every time I get the error '"validationFunction" is not a function'. Very need your help. Also I will extend my SigIn component and add there another validation functions, so this is very important to me

SignIn component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { MyButton, MyTextInput, Header } from '../uikit'
import { styles } from '../constants/constants'
import { LOG_IN } from '../routes'
import { isEnoughSymbols } from '../validation/isEnoughSymbols'

export class SignIn extends Component {
    state = {
        symbolsValidation: true
    }

    isEnoughSymbols = (text) => {
        if (text.trim().length < 8)
            this.setState({ symbolsValidation: false })
    }

    render() {
        const { mainContainer, buttons } = styles



        return (
            <View>
                <View style={mainContainer}>
                    <MyTextInput
                        placeholder={'Email/Login'}
                        isSecure={false}
                        errorText={"Incorrect email format!"}
                    />
                    <MyTextInput
                        placeholder={'Password'}
                        isSecure={true}
                        errorText={'Password must contain at least 8 symbols!'}
                        validationFunction={this.isEnoughSymbols.bind(this)}
                    />
                    <MyTextInput
                        placeholder={'Confirm password'}
                        isSecure={true}
                        errorText={"Passwords don't match"}
                    />
                    <View style={buttons}>
                        <MyButton
                            name={'confirm'.toUpperCase()}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(LOG_IN)} />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

And MyTextInput component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { w, width, h } from '../constants/constants'
import { ErrorMessage } from '.'
//import { isEnoughSymbols } from '../validation/isEnoughSymbols'

const MyTextInput = ({ placeholder, isSecure, errorText, validationFunction }) => {
    let isValid = true
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.text}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                secureTextEntry={isSecure}
                onEndEditing={(e) => validationFunction(e.nativeEvent.text)}
            >
            </TextInput>
            {
                isValid ? null : <ErrorMessage
                    errorText={errorText}
                />
            }

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },

    text: {
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        fontSize: 30,
        width: w - w / 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        textAlign: 'left',
        marginTop: 20,
        color: 'black'
    },
}
)

export { MyTextInput }
```

Comment: You're not passing `validationFunction` to all instances of `MyTextInput` so you get that error. you either need to invoke function in `MyTextInput` only if it's there or you need to pass some dummy function

Comment: Null check in child with Optional Chaining: `onEndEditing={(e) => validationFunction?.(e.nativeEvent.text)}`.

Comment: Can I aslo ask you how to get props from my SigIn component?

Comment: Can you clarify what props and where?

Comment: I need to check state in SignIn.js of symbolsValidation and send it to MyInput.js. If symbolsValidation isn't true, I will show an error

Comment: So are you needing to pass an additional prop, say `errorEnabled`, to `MyInput` component and add to the error display ternary?

Comment: Sometthing like this